# How to re-indent Atom JS React Native component code?

Tags: react-native, atom-editor

I wanted to well structured after writing the code in js components. How can I do this? Is there any shortcut key to do this?

Comment: You might want to look at [atom-beautify](https://atom.io/packages/atom-beautify) or [prettier-atom](https://atom.io/packages/prettier-atom).

Comment: Thank you @Dan Lowe